Migration of Workflow from Spyder IDE to PyCharm: Code snippet execution and variable explorer
I currently use the Spyder IDE and have often thought about migrating to PyCharm but there is one feature I often use which makes it impossible for me to switch.
I very often use Spyders Code Snippet execution by marking lines of code and executing them with F9. After that I inspect the outcome of the execution in the variable explorer to debug my applications. Thus I never use/need breakpoints.
Can I apply this workflow also in PyCharm? I often tried but failed to find this functionality.


Yes, It is possible to execute only a part of your code on pycharm. To do so :

Select the cod you want to execute
Press Alt + Maj + E or right click + Execute selection in python console
Finaly, you can see the result of your code and see the differents variable in the python console and in the variables explorer


Yes, indeed this works. Not as smoothly as it used to be in Spyder but I will get used to it.
